# Looking for solution Maradb table crashes with system sudden power cut

Tags: crash, mariadb

***Looking for solution Maradb table crashes when system sudden power cut ***

**MariaDB-server version 10.1 with MyISAM storage engine**
OS Debain 9

During Executing MySQL table insert, update or drop operation with 1-second intervals power cut and after reboot Tables get crashed and the site becomes down. It's reproducible very easily.

***Here is the MariaDB error logs***
020-06-25  9:22:26 3036056384 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './xxx/cw_xyz' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2020-06-25  9:22:26 3036056384 [Warning] Checking table:   './xxx/cw_xyz'
2020-06-25  9:22:26 3036056384 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './xxx/cw_xyzz' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Any advice to get rid of the problem considering sudden power cut for the solution?

Comment: Change the table to InnoDB?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Is there any way to identify the root causes of the failure? like investigating logs/journals etc.. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> Table './xxx/cw_xyz' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

That means that the table is Engine=MyISAM.

That engine has the unfortunate flaw that power failures usually leave some tables in that state.  `CHECK TABLE` and `REPAIR TABLE` is usually the fix.  But that is a nuisance.

Engine=InnoDB, on the other hand, works differently and does not have that particular issue.  InnoDB almost always completely repairs whatever was going on at the time of the crash.  Furthermore, it leaves the tables in a consistent state, unlike MyISAM.